# run two celery task

Tags: django, django-celery, django-celery-beat

i use celery in django ,
i add a task to my project and get error, but before add this task my project is work good.

---

# app_account.celery_task.py

my first task is :

```
@shared_task
def send_birthday_email():
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, date_of_birth__isnull=False, email__isnull=False)
    time = datetime.today()
    for user in users:
        if user.date_of_birth.day == time.day and user.date_of_birth.month == time.month:
            send_mail(
                f'happy birthday',
                f'Happy birthday, dear {user.name}, have a good year',
                'local@host.com',
                [user.email],
            )
```

my new task :

```
@shared_task
def send_password_reset_mail(mail_info):
    send_mail(
        subject=mail_info['subject'],
        message=mail_info['message'],
        from_email=mail_info['from_email'],
        recipient_list=mail_info['recipient_list'],
    )
```

second task use in this signal:

```
# this signal for send email reset password
@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
        email_plaintext_message = f"your token is = {reset_password_token.key}"
    
        mail_info = {
            'subject': 'Password Reset',
            'message': email_plaintext_message,
            'from_email': 'noreply@host.com',
            'recipient_list': [reset_password_token.user.email],
        }
        send_password_reset_mail.delay(mail_info)
```

now , when i run by **python manage.py runserver** get this error

---

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/rahmanipy/Desktop/DrfBlog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_rest_passwordreset/models.py", line 121, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "/home/rahmanipy/Desktop/DrfBlog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "/home/rahmanipy/Desktop/DrfBlog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 209, in get_model
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/rahmanipy/Desktop/DrfBlog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/rahmanipy/Desktop/DrfBlog/app_account/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app_account.celery_tasks import send_password_reset_mail
  File "/home/rahmanipy/Desktop/DrfBlog/app_account/celery_tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app_account.models import User
ImportError: cannot import name 'User' from partially initialized module 'app_account.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/rahmanipy/Desktop/DrfBlog/app_account/models.py)
```

can anyone help me ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inline import `User` inside your first task to avoid the circular import.

```
@shared_task
def send_birthday_email():
    from app_account.models import User
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, date_of_birth__isnull=False, email__isnull=False)
    time = datetime.today()
    for user in users:
        if user.date_of_birth.day == time.day and user.date_of_birth.month == time.month:
            send_mail(
                f'happy birthday',
                f'Happy birthday, dear {user.name}, have a good year',
                'local@host.com',
                [user.email],
            )
```

Comment: @AliRahmani It is a circular import, you are importing something from a module which is also trying to import something from you. That happens when Django is loading an application because it tries to import every model submodule which might then reference each other. When you move to the inline that won't happen because the import will run only when your task is called.